# Typescript Bing Ads Universal Event Tracking typings definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, global, typescript-typings

I have search the interwebs high and low, but I can't find the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) for Micrsoft's UET javascript package.

Does anyone know where this is, or how to roll your own?

I currently do this:

```
declare const uetq:any;

export class AnalyticsService implements IAnalyticsService {
...
  trackForm<T>(eventCategory:string,
             eventAction:string,
             eventLabel?:string,
             eventValue?:number):JQueryPromise<T> {
  ...
  uetq.push({"ec": eventCategory, "ea": eventAction, "el": eventLabel, "ev": 
eventValue})
  ...
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at UET.validateValue (bat.js:1)
```

When I console.log `uetq` it looks fine to me ( exists etc )

Thanks.

Comment: I did fix the error. `eventLabel` and `eventValue` must have a value, otherwise Bing will barf.